GridDB Cluster and Node Monitoring
Since I am familiar with utilizing GridDB to store sensor data, I am storing data in a similar application where the system needs to be responsive to the real-time minor pressure changes in the room coming from the pressure sensor. Due to the criticality of the application, a large amount of data is being inflowed in GridDB as the input is recorded every minute from the pressure sensor, and reliance on clusters and their respective nodes is necessary. Therefore, I am taking incremental backups every 24 hours.
The code is as follows:
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws GSException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("notificationAddress", "239.0.0.1");
    props.setProperty("notificationPort", "10000");
    props.setProperty("clusterName", "myCluster");
    props.setProperty("user", "admin");
    props.setProperty("password", "admin");

    GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);

    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        try {
            monitorClusterHealth(store);
        } catch (GSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        try {
            performBackup(store);
        } catch (GSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, 0, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS);

    simulateOperations(store);

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    store.close();
}

private static void monitorClusterHealth(GridStore store) throws GSException {
    System.out.println("Cluster Health: " + store.getPartitionController().getPartitionCount());
}

private static void performBackup(GridStore store) throws GSException {
    BackupProperties backupProps = new BackupProperties();
    backupProps.incrementalBackup(false);
    store.backup("Backup_Directory", backupProps);
}

private static void actionsPressureSensor(GridStore store) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        double pressure = inputPressureSensor(); 
        if (pressure > 50) {
            System.out.println("High pressure detected!");
            // ...
        }
        try {
            Point row = new Point();
            row.timestamp = new Date();
            row.pressure = pressure;
            store.put(row);
        } catch (GSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

static class Point {
    @RowKey Date timestamp;
    double pressure;
}

However, I need to learn how to monitor the node health of each cluster. In addition, is there any GridDB built-in library or functions or a better way to help monitor and alert if any cluster or node malfunctions?
Thank you in advance for your help.
